# ¿Cómo sumar elementos en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Muy buenas y muchas gracias de antemano. Tengo el siguiente programa que tiene que sumar todos los múltiplos que se encuentran en una lista pero no se como hacerlo. Adjunto el código que tengo hecho por el momento

```
import functions


numeros1 = [3,5,4,3,6,8]

numeros2 = [2,3,5,8,2,4]

multiplo = 3

inicio = numeros_functions.python_function(numeros1+numeros2)

print(inicio)




def python_function(numeros1,numeros2, multiplo):

 inicio = 0

 for i in range(len(numeros1)):

      if i % multiplo == 0:

         inicio += 1

      return inicio
```

Comment: ¿Cual sería el output de este código?

Comment: Hola Juan. Bienvenido a stackoverflow en Español. No acabo de entender bien tu problema. Dices que quieres sumar todos los elementos que tienes en una lista que sean múltiplos de un tercer número? Lo digo porque veo la llamada a tu función no corresponde a su definición, además, me confunde mucho el uso de dos listas. Podrías explicarte mejor. Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Por favor no generes más trabajo a los otros usuarios vandalizando tu publicación. Publicando en la red [SE] otorgaste derechos no revocables, bajo la [licencia CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) para que SE pueda distribuir su contenido. Por política de SE, cualquier clase de vandalismo será revertido. Si queres saber más sobre cómo eliminar una publicación, considera mirar: [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/).

Comment: mira por favor el [tour] y fijate como funciona el sitio. Si la respuesta que te dieron sirvio aceptala. Si no, puedes responder vos mismo a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Yo utilizaría la librería numpy, es muy potente.

A modo de ejemplo:

```
import numpy as np
lista = [2,3,4,5,7,6,9,4,10,45,12]
a = np.array(lista)
divisor = 2
suma = a.sum(where=((a%divisor)==0))
print("\nLa suma de todos los elementos del array que son multiplos de ",divisor, " es igual a ", suma )
```

Me explico:

1. **a = np.array(lista)** --> convierte tu lista a una array de una dimensión de numpy.
2. **suma = a.sum(where=((a%divisor)==0))** --> suma todos los elementos de la array que cumplen la condición where, en este caso la consición es que el resto de la división sea 0.

> PD: En realidad (a%divisor)==0 devuelve un matriz de booleanos con el
>   mismo número de elementos que la matriz a (o la lista). P.e, si el
>   elemento i=2 es True, entonces el elemento i=2 de la lista será
>   múltiplo, False en caso contrario. Para lista =
>   [2,3,4,5,7,6,9,4,10,45,12] tendremos [True, False, True, False, False,
>   True, False, True, True, False, True].  Esta matriz de booleanos en la
>   que utiliza la función sum de numpy para condicionar de la suma total.

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver un problema es mejor dividirlo en problemas más pequeños, por lo que para este caso, lo primero sería unir las dos listas con

```
numeros1 + numeros2  #esto en tu caso nos daría [3, 5, 4, 3, 6, 8, 2, 3, 5, 8, 2, 4]
```

Lo siguiente sería filtrar los que son divisibles entre el múltiplo, es decir aquellos en que al dividirlos dan resto cero. Existe la función `filter(function, sequence)` en python a la que le puedes pasar una función y un iterable y devolverá aquellos elementos del iterable en que la condición se cumpla. Con `x % multiplo == 0` conseguiríamos esto pero hay que pasárselo dentro de una función `lambda`.

```
filter(lambda x: x % multiplo == 0, numeros1 + numeros2)
# En tu caso con esto nos devolvería un filter object que contiene [3, 3, 6, 3]
```

Por último habría que sumar los elementos con la funcioón `sum()` y ya lo tendrías, quedando la función así:

```
def python_function(numeros1, numeros2, multiplo):
    filtrados = filter(lambda x: x % multiplo == 0, numeros1 + numeros2)
    return sum(filtrados)
```

Si lo aplicas a tus entradas:

```
multiplo = 3
numeros1 = [3, 5, 4, 3, 6, 8]
numeros2 = [2, 3, 5, 8, 2, 4]

print(python_function(numeros1, numeros2, multiplo))
```

Verás que te devuelve 15

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haria asi si te sirve

```
def python_function(numeros1,numeros2, multiplo):

 suma = 0

 for i in numeros1:

      if i % multiplo == 0:

         suma+=i

 for i in numeros2:
      if i % multiplo == 0:

         suma+=i

 return suma

numeros1 = [3,5,4,3,6,8]

numeros2 = [2,3,5,8,2,4]

multiplo = 3


print(python_function(numeros1,numeros2,multiplo))
```

Basicamente la funcion recorre las listas y si el valor es multiplo de 3 lo suma a la variable suma

Comment: Recuerda complementar tu código sugerido con un comentario breve sobre por qué resuelve la pregunta :)

Answer (score 0):

De hecho, para calcular la suma, sólo se requiere una línea.

```
multiplo = 3
numeros1 = [3, 5, 4, 3, 6, 8]
numeros2 = [2, 3, 5, 8, 2, 4]

print(sum([ n for n in numeros1 + numeros2 if n % multiplo == 0]))
```

La última sentencia realiza lo siguiente:

1. Construye una nueva lista con la unión de las dos listas (**numeros1 + numeros2**).
2. Genera un nueva lista iterando sobre cada elemento de la nuva lista (**n for n in**), pero sólo selecciona los multiplos de 3 (**if n % multiplo == 0**).
3. Suma los elementos de la lista resultante (**sum([...])**).
4. Y finalmente imprime el resultado (**print(...)**).

Answer (score 0):

De este modo me parece bien

```
def python_function(numeros, multiplo):
    return sum([n for n in numeros if n % multiplo == 0])

numeros1 = [3,5,4,3,6,8]
numeros2 = [2,3,5,8,2,4]
multiplo = 3

inicio = python_function(numeros1+numeros2, multiplo)

print(inicio)
```

Answer (score 0):

Espero que esta sintaxis te resulte sencilla de entender ya que estas comenzando a programar. Basicamente lo que hace la funcion `sumar_multiplos()` es recibir un array, y el multiplo como parametros, luego recorre cada uno de los numeros en el array, y si este es multiplo del parametro `if (numero % multiplo) == 0:` lo suma y por ultimo devuelve el total.

```
numeros1 = [3,5,4,3,6,8]
numeros2 = [2,3,5,8,2,4]
mul = 3

def sumar_multiplos(numeros, multiplo):
    total = 0
    for numero in numeros:
        if (numero % multiplo) == 0:
            total += numero
    return total

subtotal1 = sumar_multiplos(numeros1, mul)
subtotal2 = sumar_multiplos(numeros2, mul)

print("Subtotal 1: ", subtotal1)
print("Subtotal 2: ", subtotal2)
print("TOTAL: ", subtotal2 + subtotal1)
```

Salida:

```
# Subtotal 1:  12
# Subtotal 2:  3
# TOTAL:  15
```